# (osd_cat) Cyrillic character output

Tags: debian, xorg, debian-squeeze

All been great with my Cyrillic character output in osd_cat until I created `~/.fonts.conf` (at least this is the most obvious reason I'd think) with such settings (as seen on [debian forum](http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=38534&start=75#p363453)):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
<fontconfig>
<match target="font">
<edit mode="assign" name="rgba">
<const>rgb</const>
</edit>
</match>
<match target="font">
<edit mode="assign" name="hinting">
<bool>true</bool>
</edit>
</match>
<match target="font">
<edit mode="assign" name="hintstyle">
<const>hintmedium</const>
</edit>
</match>
<match target="font">
<edit mode="assign" name="antialias">
<bool>true</bool>
</edit>
</match>
<match target="font">
<edit mode="assign" name="lcdfilter">
<const>lcddefault</const>
</edit>
</match>
</fontconfig>
```

After that (and system reboot, of course) fonts look "better", but any Cyrillic word is shown as `.`. Here are my osd_cat script settings:

```
/usr/bin/osd_cat -f -*-*-*-*-*-*-20-*-*-*-*-*-koi8-r --delay=4 -c green -s 1 -A center -p top -o 45 --age=4;
```

I already tried specifying some server-side monospaced fonts (koi8-r), found through `xlsfonts -fn '*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-c*'` command, e.g.

```
/usr/bin/osd_cat -f -misc-fixed-medium-r-normal--0-0-100-100-c-0-koi8-r --delay=4 -c green -s 1 -A center -p top -o 45 --age=4;
```

but nothing seems to be changing.

Please, help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a locale problem. Was fixed by adding

```
export LC_ALL="ru_RU.koi8-r"
```

line in my initial script.